# How to call function on route change in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, e-commerce

Using `react-router-dom` v6 on an ecommerce site. I need to handle the case where the user clicks away from the checkout in the middle of entering info. I want to call a function that resets the checkout data if the route changes.

So basically, if current url contains `"checkout"` and the url changes, call `resetCheckout()`. How would I implement this in React? I tried adding a `useEffect()` to my checkout route that has `window.location.href` as a dependency. This did not work. I'm assuming because the url is changed before the effect can be called? Anyone know how to do this? For the sake of clarity, below is the hook I'm trying to use in my `<Checkout />` component:

```
useEffect(() => {
  resetCheckout();
}, [window.location.href]);
```

And here is my necessary route structure in `App.js`:

```
const App = () => {
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
      <Route path="/checkout" element={<Checkout />} />
      <Route path="*" element={<Navigate to="/" replace />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};
```

One solution is to put a hook inside `App.js` but I'd like to keep this functionality inside `<Checkout />` if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may just be more trivially simple to reset the checkout *whatever* in a cleanup function when the `Checkout` component unmounts.

Example:

```
const Checkout = () => {

  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      // cleanup when component unmounts
      console.log("leaving checkout");
      resetCheckout();
    };
  }, []);

  ...

};
```